# C# Copy all object parameters to child class object

Tags: c#, copy-constructor

Suppose I have an object of a parent class which I can't change - for example, an instance of `ListBox` with long list of parameters. Now I create a child class:

```
class PlaylistBox : ListBox
{

    void CopySettingsFrom(ListBox In)
    {
         //...what now?
    }
}
```

Question - how can I efficiently make a shallow copy from `In` object to the new object of `PlaylistBox`?

Comment: If `Listbox` implements `ICloneable`, you call `Clone`. Otherwise you write the code. There is no magic to this.

Comment: Depends on if you need only the public properties and fields of the base-class or also internal or private members. Basically you just write `this.MyProperty = In.MyProperty` for every single field/property you want to copy. Reflection may help if there are lots of them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Within the constructor calling `Clone` wouldn´t help much, as it *returns* an instance which you can´t assign to `this` apparently. YOu´d have to copy the members of the clone to the new instance anyway.

Comment: what does "efficiently" mean exactly here? you don't wont to write down the initialization of all public properties and fields one by one ?=!

Comment: Yes, I don't want to write them one by one :)

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's the other thing - there's no copying involved here. `In` isn't a `PlaylistBox`. This isn't a *copy* constructor. Only a subset of properties can be copied. Copying a UI control doesn't make a lot of sense since you can't copy its handles and resources

Comment: @Ch3shire well, you'll have to. You can't copy *all* of them. You can't copy any GDI handles and resources for example. Or Font objects. Data bindings. This isn't a copy constructor. It's a constructor that will copy a *few* properties into the new project, if it's able to.

Comment: You have to indicate *which* members you want to copy.

Comment: The other thing is that a *UI Control* has to be constructed before you can set some of its properties. Instead of a constructor, add a `CopySettingstFrom(ListBox)` *instance* method

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection

```
//Other Imports...
using System.Reflection;

public PlaylistBox(ListBox In)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ListBox).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
        if (p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            p.SetMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { p.GetMethod.Invoke(In, null) });
}
```

For .NET < 4.5, substitute calls to the [`GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod) and [`SetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod) properties with calls to the [`GetGetMethod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getgetmethod) and [`GetSetMethod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod) methods respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example  with 3 methods, based on reflection and AutoMapper with explanation:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example1();
            Example2();
            Example3();
        }

        public static void Example1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This example shows using copy with reflection. Minus of this method - u have to implement FULL copy for each class or u will copy only references to object properties");

            //creating new parent class with some values
            var parentClass = new ParentClass
            {
                Property1 = "qqq",
                Property2 = 1,
                ObjectProperty = new SomeClassWithObjectProperty
                {
                    ObjectProperty = new SomeObjectClass {SomeProperty = "www"}
                }
            };

            //crating new child class and copy REFERENCES to properties
            var childClassReflection = new ChildClassReflection(parentClass);

            //changing properties of parent
            parentClass.Property1 = "rrr";
            parentClass.Property2 = 2;
            parentClass.ObjectProperty.ObjectProperty.SomeProperty = "eee";

            //we will get OLD values for VALUE types and OLD values for REFERENCE types
            //qqq 1 WWW
            Console.WriteLine(childClassReflection.Property1 + " " + childClassReflection.Property2 + " " + childClassReflection.ObjectProperty.ObjectProperty.SomeProperty);
        }

        public static void Example2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This example shows using copy with reflection WITH FULL COPY");

            //creating new parent class with some values
            var parentClass = new ParentClass
            {
                Property1 = "qqq",
                Property2 = 1,
                ObjectProperty = new SomeClassWithObjectProperty
                {
                    ObjectProperty = new SomeObjectClass {SomeProperty = "www"}
                }
            };

            //crating new child class and copy REFERENCES to properties
            var childClassReflection = new ChildClassReflectionWithFullCopy(parentClass);

            //changing properties of parent
            parentClass.Property1 = "rrr";
            parentClass.Property2 = 2;
            parentClass.ObjectProperty.ObjectProperty.SomeProperty = "eee";

            //we will get OLD values for VALUE types and NEW values for REFERENCE types
            //qqq 1 eee
            Console.WriteLine(childClassReflection.Property1 + " " + childClassReflection.Property2 + " " + childClassReflection.ObjectProperty.ObjectProperty.SomeProperty);
        }

        public static void Example3()
        {
            //here i will show copy using AutoMapper
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This example shows using copy with AutoMapper");

            //creating new parent class with some values
            var parentClass = new ParentClass
            {
                Property1 = "qqq",
                Property2 = 1,
                ObjectProperty = new SomeClassWithObjectProperty
                {
                    ObjectProperty = new SomeObjectClass { SomeProperty = "www" }
                }
            };

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ParentClass, ChildClassAutoMapper>());           

            //crating new child class and copy REFERENCES to properties
            var childClassReflection = Mapper.Map<ChildClassAutoMapper>(parentClass);

            //changing properties of parent
            parentClass.Property1 = "rrr";
            parentClass.Property2 = 2;
            parentClass.ObjectProperty.ObjectProperty.SomeProperty = "eee";

            //we will get OLD values for VALUE types and OLD values for REFERENCE types
            //qqq 1 eee
            Console.WriteLine(childClassReflection.Property1 + " " + childClassReflection.Property2 + " " + childClassReflection.ObjectProperty.ObjectProperty.SomeProperty);
        }
    }

    public class ChildClassAutoMapper:ParentClass
    {       
    }

    public class ChildClassReflection : ParentClass
    {
        public ChildClassReflection(ParentClass parentClass)
        {
            foreach (var p in ParentProperties)
                p.SetMethod.Invoke(this, new[] {p.GetMethod.Invoke(parentClass, null)});
        }

        //do it only once for best performance
        private static PropertyInfo[] ParentProperties { get; } = typeof(ParentClass).GetProperties().Where(c => c.CanRead && c.CanWrite).ToArray();
    }

    public class ChildClassReflectionWithFullCopy : ParentClass
    {
        public ChildClassReflectionWithFullCopy(ParentClass parentClass)
        {
            var parentClassLocal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentClass>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parentClass));
            foreach (var p in ParentProperties)
                p.SetMethod.Invoke(this, new[] {p.GetMethod.Invoke(parentClassLocal, null)});
        }

        //do it only once for best performance
        private static PropertyInfo[] ParentProperties { get; } = typeof(ParentClass).GetProperties().Where(c => c.CanRead && c.CanWrite).ToArray();
    }

    public class ParentClass
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public int Property2 { get; set; }
        public SomeClassWithObjectProperty ObjectProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClassWithObjectProperty
    {
        public SomeObjectClass ObjectProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeObjectClass
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
```